# Indirection without using eval

Tags: arrays, bash, indirection

I'm looking for a clean way (without eval command) to do an indirect reference to an array. Here is a more precise description of what I want :

```
function valueof {
   echo "indirection1 \$$1=${!1}"
   eval "echo indirection2 \\\$$1=\${$1[@]}" # Untill this step its fine.

   # My final objective is to do this (but eval is not a very sexy solution) : 
   for i in $(eval "echo \${$1[@]}") ; do 
      echo $i
   done

   # Here is the "problem", ie. "bad substitution"
   echo "indirection3 \$$1=${!1[@]}"  
   # "1[@]" is evaluated first i guess?
}
```

With the following valueof calls :

```
a=("a" "aa" "aaa")
b=("b" "bb" "bbb")
valueof a
valueof b
```

The output I have is :

```
indirection1 $a=a
indirection2 $a=a aa aaa
a
aa
aaa
indirection1 $b=b
indirection2 $b=b bb bbb
b
bb
bbb
```

On stderr :

```
prog.sh: line 10: indirection3 $1=${!1[@]}: bad substitution
prog.sh: line 10: indirection3 $1=${!1[@]}: bad substitution
```

Thanks for your answers/remarks on this question :)

Comment: BTW, your error is the result of the unfortunate design decision of ksh, which used prefixes combined with postfixes as expansion operators, and bash's inheriting that, plus creating their own conflicting use of the `!` prefix for indirection (which has yet another conflicting use related to indirection in other shells). `"${!var[@]}"` means to expand var's list of keys, and gets higher precedence than `${!var}`.

Comment: Ok, thank you for that precision. That's why in your code we can see something like `'"$1"'`, in order to expand that part first?

Comment: Partially, but it's also taking advantage of some gory details over the way arguments to "declaration commands" are conditionally parsed in Bash so that you get an eval-like double expansion under certain conditions (it isn't a bug). The other kinds of indirection being used are implicit arithmetic variable indirection, and taking advantage of subscript syntax being considered part of the parameter name indirectly. None of this is really "supported" and I spent way too much time discovering it in order to write better reusable libraries (which nobody can decypher.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest building Bash from the git devel branch and using `typeset -n` like most other sane shells with arrays do. All other solutions involving functions and arrays require either `eval` or exploiting quirky undocumented behaviours. Both require about equal care and there isn't necessarily an advantage to one over the other.

Here is a general example which demonstrates just about everything you can do indirectly without eval. Namespace collisions are still possible.

```
isSubset() {
    local -a 'xkeys=("${!'"$1"'[@]}")' 'ykeys=("${!'"$2"'[@]}")'
    set -- "${@/%/[key]}"

    (( ${#xkeys[@]} <= ${#ykeys[@]} )) || return 1

    local key
    for key in "${xkeys[@]}"; do
        [[ ${!2+_} && ${!1} == "${!2}" ]] || return 1
    done
}

a=(abc def [4]=ghi jkl)
b=(abc def [4]=ghi jkl)
c=(abc [3]=def [6]=ghi xyz)
isSubset a b
echo $? # 0
isSubset b c
echo $? # 1
```

This is really `eval` in disguise in some respects. Most people are unaware that they are effectively performing eval any time they pass variable names to builtins and arithmetic expressions. You have to always ensure that variable names and indexes are controlled internally and never influenced by user input or other side-effects that you can't guarantee the results of.

Judging by your misuse of wordsplitting and quoting, you should probably just switch to a different language. Bash isn't really meant to deal with safe encapsulation.