# Explaining local -a 'xkeys=("${!'"$1"'[@]}")'

Tags: arrays, bash, indirection

This code is given as a workaround for array indirection at [bash-hackers.org wiki page](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arrays#indirection) as an example to get array length and indices indirectly.

It's also mentioned in this [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13541465/indirection-without-using-eval).

I would like to understand specifically why `local -a 'xkeys=("${!'"$1"'[@]}")'` works. What is happening here. I understand that there are three different strings to the right of the equal sign:

1. 'xkeys=("${!'
2. "$1"
3. '[@]}")'

Why does that work?

This is the code:

```
isSubset() {
local -a 'xkeys=("${!'"$1"'[@]}")' 'ykeys=("${!'"$2"'[@]}")'
set -- "${@/%/[key]}"

(( ${#xkeys[@]} <= ${#ykeys[@]} )) || return 1

local key
for key in "${xkeys[@]}"; do
    [[ ${!2+_} && ${!1} == ${!2} ]] || return 1
done
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I just explained a bunch of the operation of `isSubset` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26499268/258523) though not specifically this bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@tripleee is essentially right, though one detail was missed (and I made the same mistake initially a few minutes ago when writing my explanation of the rest of `isSubset` in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26499268/258523)).

The crucial detail here is that `local` (and `declare` and `typeset`) do their *own* parsing of their arguments.

Let's walk through the various expansions of this line

```
local -a 'xkeys=("${!'"$1"'[@]}")' 'ykeys=("${!'"$2"'[@]}")'
```

Splitting the quoted pieces for now will aid in understanding. That gets us

```
local -a 'xkeys=("${!' "$1" '[@]}")' 'ykeys=("${!' "$2" '[@]}")'
```

Which expands to

```
local -a 'xkeys=("${!' "a" '[@]}")' 'ykeys=("${!' "b" '[@]}")'
```

Which reassembles into

```
local -a 'xkeys=("${!'"a"'[@]}")' 'ykeys=("${!'"a"'[@]}")'
```

Combining adjacent quoted words gets us

```
local -a 'xkeys=("${!a[@]}")' 'ykeys=("${!a[@]}")'
```

If this was anything but `local` we would be done at this point (ok `eval` also).

For example `echo`: `e() { echo 'xkeys=("${!'"$1"'[@]}")' 'ykeys=("${!'"$2"'[@]}")'; }; e a b` outputs `xkeys=("${!a[@]}") ykeys=("${!b[@]}")`

But since this is `local` which, as I said before, does its own parsing (and in fact you know it does already because otherwise the `{0..5}` expansions in the assignment to `a` wouldn't have worked. Try `echo {0..5} vs. "{0..5}"` to see what I mean) the single-quoted strings get re-evaluated by `local` and the array index expansions occur. So `${!a[@]}` expands to the indices of `a` and `${!b[@]}` expands to the indices of `b`.

Answer (score 1):

`${!"$1"}` fetches the variable named in `$1`. `${variable[@]}` expands to all the elements in the array `variable`. So this basically copies the array named by `$1` into `xkeys`.

Comment: I understand that that is what it's supposed to be. I guess the question is why does it work this specific way but not when I put it as just one string (i.e. remove the single quotes). For more context you can see some of my explorations [here](http://ahmed.amayem.com/bash-indirect-expansion-exploration/#accessing_array_length_indices)

Comment: The `!` isn't swallowed as part of the expansion of `$1` it is array index expansion (as opposed to array value expansion). The overloaded nature of `!` in this position is complicated and confusing.