# dissecting this code, explanation - check if array subset of another array

Tags: arrays, bash, expansion

I found this example at `wiki.bash-hackers.org`, however it is not explained in
detail, so I was hoping maybe someone here, could put some light on this, and explain
what is happening.

I understand the first line of `isSubset` function, as it is taking passed args, and using indirect
referencing, stores keys into internal arrays `xkeys` and `ykeys`.

2nd line is setting parameters, but I don't understand what `${@/%/[key]}` is doing?
Looks like substitution, changing `%` to `[key]`, I have no clue what happens here.

Then in next line it compares arrays on number of elements, but shouldn't it be reverse,
returning 1 if first array has more elements, because then it can't be subset of the second one?

Finally `[[ ${!2+_} && ${!1} == ${!2} ]] || return 1`, is pretty confusing.

```
isSubset() {
    local -a 'xkeys=("${!'"$1"'[@]}")' 'ykeys=("${!'"$2"'[@]}")'
    set -- "${@/%/[key]}"

    (( ${#xkeys[@]} <= ${#ykeys[@]} )) || return 1

    local key
    for key in "${xkeys[@]}"; do
        [[ ${!2+_} && ${!1} == ${!2} ]] || return 1
    done
}

main() {
    # "a" is a subset of "b"
    local -a 'a=({0..5})' 'b=({0..10})'
    isSubset a b
    echo $? # true

    # "a" contains a key not in "b"
    local -a 'a=([5]=5 {6..11})' 'b=({0..10})'
    isSubset a b
    echo $? # false

    # "a" contains an element whose value != the corresponding member of "b"
    local -a 'a=([5]=5 6 8 9 10)' 'b=({0..10})'
    isSubset a b
    echo $? # false
}

main
```

Comment: Entirely without snark. print out the intermediate values after each line to see what they are doing and you'll find out. (Use `declare -p <variable>` not `echo`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2nd line:

```
    ${@/%/[key]}
```

`%` as first character of the pattern indicates that pattern has to match at the end. There is nothing else in the pattern so the meaning is "replace empty string at the end, with '[key]'". After that positional parameters look like this:

```
    1 = a[key]
    2 = b[key]
```

Next line:

> but shouldn't it be reverse, returning 1 if first array has more elements,

But it does that. Notice that `||` operator is used, so it will return `1` if the condition is *not* met. The condition is: "x.size <= y.size", so it will return `1` if "x.size > y.size".

Finally:

```
    [[ ${!2+_} && ${!1} == ${!2} ]] || return 1
```

To be honest, I don't know what `+_` is for. As for the rest, notice that we are in a loop with a `key` variable. We also have `key` in our positional variables, so:

```
    ${!1}
```

becomes

```
    ${a[key])
```

and `key` variable takes values of keys from array `a`. So the whole test verifies that value with given key exists in the second array:

```
    [[ ${!2+_} && ...
```

and that value with that key in the first array is the same as the value with that key in the second array:

```
    ... && ${!1} == ${!2} ]]
```

The first condition is necessary to detect the case when you pass array `a` which at index `i` has empty string and array `b` which doesn't have index `i`:

```
local -a 'a=([1]="" 2 3)' 'b=([2]=2 {3..10})'
isSubset a b
echo $? # false
```

Comment: totally overseen `[[ ${!2+_} && ${!1} == ${!2} ]] || return 1` `||` in here, probably to much staring at screen, was interpreting this as `then` instead of `or`.. thanks for explaining other things!

Answer (score 1):

The explanation for `${@/%/[key]}` is this section of the bash man page:

> ${parameter/pattern/string}
>
> The pattern is expanded to produce a pattern just as in pathname
>      expansion.   Parameter is expanded and the longest match of pat-
>      tern against its value is replaced  with  string.   If  Ipattern
>      begins  with /, all matches of pattern are replaced with string.
>      Normally only the first match is replaced.   If  pattern  begins
>      with  #, it must match at the beginning of the expanded value of
>      parameter.  If pattern begins with %, it must match at  the  end
>      of  the expanded value of parameter.  If string is null, matches
>      of pattern are deleted and the / following pattern may be  omit-
>      ted.   If  parameter  is  @  or *, the substitution operation is
>      applied to each positional parameter in turn, and the  expansion
>      is  the  resultant list.  If parameter is an array variable sub-
>      scripted with @ or *, the substitution operation is  applied  to
>      each  member  of  the  array  in  turn, and the expansion is the
>      resultant list.

Specifically the bit about `%` there in the middle. So `${@/%/[key]}` is matching the end of the string for each value in the array and appending `[key]` to it.

Assuming a call to `isSubset` of `isSubset a b` where `a='([0]="0" [1]="1" [2]="2" [3]="3" [4]="4" [5]="5")'` and `b='([0]="0" [1]="1" [2]="2" [3]="3" [4]="4" [5]="5" [6]="6" [7]="7" [8]="8" [9]="9" [10]="10")'`. What happens in `isSubset` goes like this:

```
isSubset() {
    local -a 'xkeys=("${!'"$1"'[@]}")' 'ykeys=("${!'"$2"'[@]}")'
```

Interpolate `$1` and `$2` into the above line and we get

```
    local -a 'xkeys=("${!a[@]}")' 'ykeys=("${!b[@]}")'
```

Which expands to (via `${!arr[@]}` array index expansion)

```
    local -a 'xkeys=(0 1 2 3 4 5)' 'ykeys=(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)'
```

At this point we now have `xkeys` and `ykeys` arrays of the keys of the arrays passed in.

```
    set -- "${@/%/[key]}"
```

Recall that `$@` is `@=(a b)` and from the man page snippet above we know that this becomes

```
    set -- 'a[key]' 'b[key]'
```

`set --` then sets the functions positional parameters for us so we have `@=('a[key]' 'b[key]')`

```
    (( ${#xkeys[@]} <= ${#ykeys[@]} )) || return 1
```

If `xkeys` is larger than `ykeys` then it can't be a subset so bail out. (This could be done before the `set --` line and that would be slightly more efficient I imagine, though unlikely to matter in any but the hottest of loops.)

```
    local key
    for key in "${xkeys[@]}"; do
```

Loop over every key in `xkeys` (with the value assigned to `key`). (Note the variable name here, it is crucial.)[1]

```
        [[ ${!2+_} && ${!1} == ${!2} ]] || return 1
```

More indirection, this time on the positional parameters. The above expands to

```
        [[ ${b[key]+_} && ${a[key]} == ${b[key]} ]] || return 1
```

`${b[key]+_}` expands to _ if `b[key]` has a value and an empty string if it does not. (I'm not sure why this bothers with the alternate value expansion instead of just using `${!2}` but there is probably a reason. It could be safety in the face of `set -u` or it could be safety against `[[` interpreting the resulting string, though I don't think it does that but `[` would have.) This test therefore passes when `b[key]` has a value and fails when it does not.

`${a[key]} == ${b[key]}` tests that the value in that index is the same in both arrays and the whole expression returns failure from the function when either part fails.

@danadam correctly explains, and it makes sense to include here as well, that the key detail here is that the `[]` indexing in array lookups does variable expansion so `a[key]` in positional parameter one is not looking for the "key" index in array `a` but is rather `a[$key]`.

```
    done
}
```

I hope that all made sense. (And I hope I got it all right. =)

1. I *really* wanted to write "Note the variable name here, it is ... key." but the ensuing confusion wasn't worth the joke.

Comment: Re. "alternate value expansion", I was (still am) a bit confused because I thought that the format is ``${parameter:+word}`` (with colon).

Comment: @danadam The manual has a one sentence mention of what the colon means there. It means "or null". `When not performing substring expansion, bash tests for a parameter that is unset or null; omitting the colon results in a test only for a parameter that is unset.` It is the last sentence in the paragraph before the explanation of `:-`. In general that distinction doesn't matter to people. Here it very much does.